# Why do we take 50 ohm resistance value for unit conversion in Spectrum View in the oscilloscopes?

Tags: resistance, frequency, oscilloscope, spectrum

While we change the unit in Spectrum View, why is it explicitly mentioned 50 ohm? Why don't we take the resistance value of 1 Mohm into account as well? Though we do have 1 Mohm as one of the termination values in the oscilloscopes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some details missing in your question (especially your scope model) but this could be a general explanation. In your spectrum view (I assume some kind of FFT function) what is the unit you are choosing or is used?

- If it says V (Volt), no issue, impedance doesn't matter: the scope measures a voltage, and shows a voltage.
- If it says dBV, impedance doesn't matter, either: measures a voltage, and shows essentially a log of that: look on the net if you don't know of dB (deciBel) works. By the way, dBV are often used on 75 ohm systems.
- If it says dBm, impedance *is* very important since dBm represents a power and you can't obtain a power from a measured voltage without an impedance. For a number of reasons (and convention) usually we use 50 ohm as a reference impedance. dBm represents the ratio between the measured power and 1mW and 99% of the time the system impedance is 50 ohm but it's best to clarify it. That's what your scope probably is doing.

Another thing: many higher end scopes *have* a switchable 50 ohm input impedance (instead of the typical 1MOhm + some pF). And anyway you can buy a pass-thru terminator (which is essentially a 50 ohm resistor) and attach it to your scope: the 50 ohm dwarfes the megaohm input and essentially becomes the new input impedance.

In case of doubt *the* correct way is to read the instruction manual.